# Combine two table mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it Possible to combine these two table like this? All Subjects from table2 should be combined from table1 and the subjects should be aligned in 1 row with the same ID from table1.

```
Table1 
----------------------
ID   Student_ID   Name

 1   200000      Paul

 2   202907      Ger


Table2
----------------------
Student_ID   Subject

200000       ACT111

200000       ACT112

200000       ACT113

202907       ACT111

-------------------


Expected Combination
------------------------------------------------------
ID       Student_ID     Name            Subject
1        200000         Paul      ACT111 ACT112 ACT113
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You must relate your tables to get the data (see [`JOIN syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)), and then you can use [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get the value list separated by commas:

```sql
select t1.id, t1.student_id, t1.name
     , group_concat(t2.subject separator ',') as subjects
from table1 as t1
     inner join table2 as t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id
--   ^^^^^^^^^^ Replace 'INNER JOIN' with 'LEFT JOIN' if you want to
--              also show the students with no subjects
group by t1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`, if you expect to be no entries in `Table2` for entries in `Table1`), along with a `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Student_ID, t1.Name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.Subject SEPARATOR ' ') as Subject
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Student_ID = t2.Student_ID
GROUP BY t1.Student_ID
```

This takes rows from Table1 and adds data from rows from Table2, that have same Student_ID.

If there is no entry in Table2 for a specific student, but you still want it to be visible in the result, just replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

Read more about **[JOINs in mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)** and function [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).